# How does ASP .Net recognize delete buttons in a GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a GridView with ItemTemplate buttons that use the RowCommand function to execute an SQL. Note that one of them has the CommandName "delete" to evaluate which button was pressed. Does this cause the GridView to trigger the RowDeleting event? I assume ASP .Net thinks I created a custom delete button and therefore fires the event. I don't use the event and it throws an error trying to fire it, because it doesn't exist. Is there a way to disable that?

## GridView

```
        <asp:GridView ID="gv_uebersicht" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" OnRowCommand="gv_uebersicht_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="gv_uebersicht_RowDataBound" OnRowDeleting="gv_uebersicht_RowDeleting">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="cockpit_id" HeaderText="cockpitid" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="lieferant" HeaderText="Lieferant" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="datei" HeaderText="Dateiname" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="status" HeaderText="Status" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="erstellzeit" HeaderText="Erstellzeit" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="meldung" HeaderText="Meldung" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Aktion">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="btn_delete" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("cockpit_id") %>' CommandName='<%# "delete" %>' Text="Löschen" Visible='<%# Eval("status_id").ToString() == "2" || Eval("status_id").ToString() == "14" || Eval("status_id").ToString() == "67" || Eval("status_id").ToString() == "68" || Eval("status_id").ToString() == "999" || Eval("status_id").ToString() == "1" || Eval("status_id").ToString() == "69" %>' />
                        <asp:Button ID="btn_move" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("cockpit_id") %>' CommandName='<%# "move" %>' Text="Move" Visible='<%# Eval("status_id").ToString() == "2" || Eval("status_id").ToString() == "14" || Eval("status_id").ToString() == "67" %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="status_id" HeaderText="statusid" />
            </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#808080" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#383838" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

## RowCommand function

```
    protected void gv_uebersicht_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        string commandName = e.CommandName;
        string commandArgument = e.CommandArgument.ToString();

        lbl_msg.Text = "Die Datei " + DatabaseFunctions.GetScalar("SELECT VDB_LS_DATEI FROM VDB_LADESTATUS_COCKPIT WHERE VDB_LS_ID = " + commandArgument) + " wird " + (commandName == "move" ? "gemoved." : "gelöscht.");

        ds.UpdateCommand = @"UPDATE VDB_LADESTATUS_COCKPIT
                            SET VDB_LS_STATUS_ID = 19
                            WHERE VDB_LS_ID = " + commandArgument;
        ds.Update();
        ds.InsertCommand = @"DECLARE
                              V_RC INTEGER;
                            BEGIN
                              V_RC := Val.Loeschen_Freigabe_Funktionen(P_Cockpit_ID => " + commandArgument + @",
                                                                       P_Aktion => '" + commandName + @"');
                            END; ";
        ds.Insert();
        fill_gv_uebersicht();
    }
```

Comment: add the code you used

Comment: @SruthiSuresh done

Comment: The documentation says yes, the RowDeleting event is triggered: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand(v=vs.110).aspx  To disable this behavior, the obvious solution is to change the command name to something other than one of the predefined names.

Comment: @Joe I don't want to change the `CommandName` though, is there a way to disable the `GridView` from doing that?

Comment: @lenny You could handle the `RowDeleting` event and set GridViewDeleteEventArgs.Cancel to true to stop the row from being deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `GridView` trigger the `RowDeleting` event, because `CommandName` of the button is **delete**. You have to change your `CommandName` and have to remove `OnRowDeleting="gv_uebersicht_RowDeleting"` from your `GridView` control. It will not throw any error.

Comment: is there a way to disable this functionality? I don't want the `RowDeleting` event to be fired, just because one of my commands is called `delete`

Comment: Can you check by removing `OnRowDeleting="gv_uebersicht_RowDeleting"` from `GridView` control and code of the event from `.cs` file?

Comment: I just went ahead and changed the `CommandName` to `"del"` and change it in the `RowCommand` event to `"delete"`. it's stupid you can't turn off this functionality though